# How to get a specific Firestore document of a certain collection with a ListView.builder

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection in my firestore database named as 'testCrud', where I have carModel, and carColor.
I am trying to get carModel value in my dashboard page.
I am using QuerySnapshot cars;
Rest of the code is in picture, I don't know if data[] is deprecated?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2abq.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data` is no longer a property, it's a method.
So, try:

```dart
cars.docs[i].data()['carModel']
```

> Getting a snapshots' data via the data getter is now done via the data() method.

https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/migration